# Tableau: Multiple columns in a filter

Tags: pivot, tableau-api

I have three numeric fields named A,B,C and wants them in a single filter in tableau and based on the one selected in that filter a line chart will be shown. For e.g. in filter **Stages** B column is selected and line chart of B is shown. Had it been column A selected then line chart of A would be displayed .

Pardon my way of asking question by showing a image. I just picked up learning tableau and not getting this trick any where.

[image]

Here is the snapshot of data

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a (list) parameter named 'ABC'. With the values

```
A
B
C
```

Then create a calculated field

```
IF ABC = 'A' THEN [column_a]
 ELSEIF ABC = 'B' THEN [column_b]
 ELSEIF ABC = 'C' THEN [column_c]
END
```

Something like that should work for you. Check out Tableau training [here](https://www.tableau.com/learn/training/20202). It's free, but you have to sign up for an account.

Answer (score 1):

Another way without creating a calculated field.  Just pivot the three columns to rows and your field on which you can apply filter is created.  Let me show you

This is screenshot of input data

[image]

I converted three cols to pivots to get data reshaped like this

[image: pivoted_data]

After renaming pivoted-fields column to `Stages` I can add directly this one to view and get my desired result.

[image]